# How do I animate both parent and child on parent hover?

Tags: html, css, animation

Basically what the questions says.

Note: Sizing is arbitrary i.e. I seem to be running into the issue however I size the two divs so I haven't included the size in css.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    background-color: black;
}

#child {
    background-color: white;
}
```

I have tried appending the below:

```
@keyframes parentanim {
    from {background-color: black;}
    to {background-color: white;}
}

@keyframes childanim {
    from {background-color: white;}
    to {background-color: black;}
}

#parent:hover {
    animation: parentanim 500ms forwards;
}

#parent:hover > #child {
    animation: childanim 500ms forwards;
}
```

And it doesn't seem to be working. I am wondering if I have to pursue some sort of nesting?

PS: I am on Chrome 83.0.4103.97

Comment: Your code is fine, you've just got empty divs with no width or height. Either add in some text or give the divs an image and / or height. Quick example with text here https://jsfiddle.net/9f83vkyw/

Comment: I didn't think the sizing was important so I didn't include it. This is just the code that's pertinent to the issue. The behaviour is the same regardless of sizing

Comment: It works in the fiddle though??

Comment: Damn. And so it does. I just realized that it only seems to not work on the project that I'm working on now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you further.

```css
#parent {
    background-color: black;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

#child {
    background-color: white;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

@keyframes parentanim {
    from {background-color: black;}
    to {background-color: white;}
}

@keyframes childanim {
    from {background-color: white;}
    to {background-color: black;}
}

#parent:hover {
    animation: parentanim 2s forwards;
}

#parent:hover #child {
    animation: childanim 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't think the sizing was important so I didn't include it. This is just the code that's pertinent to the issue at hand.